# is it possible to generate a unique number given a set of N integers regardless of their permutation?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to efficiently compute an *"id"* for a set of **N** integers, the id needs to be unique if any of the numbers is different from some other set. At the same time the id needs to be the same if the numbers are sorted differently. Order matters in my case, a simple solution would be to sort the set and recursively combine them using a cantor pair function, this would guarantee my properties...the problem is that sorting is expensive (*n log(n)*) and even though n is small, I need to do N such sorts where N is very large. Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Cosmin

Comment: Integers can be sorted in linear time and you can't really expect a sublinear algorithm anyways.

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion, I forgot about radix sort, yes that would be linear for integers. I was however, hoping to avoid sorting altogether if possible

Comment: Goedel encoding $\{n_i\} \to \prod {p_i}^{n_i}$ lets you avoid sorting, but I doubt you'd want to go this way.

Comment: @user58697 How would it avoid the sorting step if the number is supposed to be *invariant* under permutations of the set?

Comment: @Cosmin I hope you do realize that the bit-length of the "id" assigned to a set will be roughly at least as large as the total bit-length of all the members of this set; so even simple mathematical operations would take time proportional to $N$ or even $N^2$ and sorting the numbers might actually be one of the cheaper parts of the whole operation. Can you elaborate a bit on *why* you need to compute the "id" in the first place?